# How can i load items back to the listView control from text file and also add checkBoxes near each item faster?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In this method i'm reading a text file from my hard disk and add the items to the listView.

I also changed in the form1 designer on the listView propeties the property CheckBoxes to true.

Now when i'm running my program it's taking like 10-15 seconds to load it up all.

The form1 constructor:

```
LoadtoListView();
```

And the method LoadtoListView:

```
private void LoadtoListView()
        {
            int countit = 0;
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"c:\listviewfile\databaseEN.txt"))
            {
                while (-1 < sr.Peek())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string name = sr.ReadLine();
                        string email = sr.ReadLine();
                        var lvi = new ListViewItem(name.Substring(name.IndexOf(":") + 1));
                        lvi.SubItems.Add(email.Substring(email.IndexOf(":") + 1));
                        listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
                        countit++;
                    }
                    catch (Exception) { }
                }
                sr.Close();
                numberofforums = countit;
            }
        }
```

There are 547 items to load and 547 checkBoxes.

I tested now if i change in the designer the listView property of the CheckBoxes to false again it will load fast about 1-2 seconds.

But once i'm turning this property of the CheckBoxes to true it's tkaing more then 10-15 seconds to load.

I guess the problem is that it's taking time to draw all the CheckBoxes.

Is there any way to make it all faster ?

Comment: do you have code handling ItemCheck events?

Comment: Plutonix no. How should i do it  ?

Comment: `File.ReadAllLines()` and you get the file as `string[]`.

Comment: @HarimAbdu you might want to have a look at [this short clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D3Y6DnFpHCA).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There exist a couple of ways you could make that faster. Actually you could make it blazingly fast, checkboxes or no checkboxes.

Your code requires a few tweaks here and there and you must think about reusability, concern separation and parameterisation.

For instance, the method name `LoadToListView` is already doing **too much work**. It loads stuff, and it also populates the listview.

There are 3 ingredients that can get you to Nirvana.

### First of all

consider creating an up front materialised list of `ListViewItem` instances, more particularly, create a primitive array, such as this (by the way, I will also sprinkle some other good practices along the way, even though it is not the lacking of those practices which causes your delays):

```
public ListViewItem[] LoadItems(string filePath) {
    // not hardcoding the filePath is a good idea

    List<ListViewItem> accumulator = new List<ListViewItem>();

    int countit = 0;
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath)) {
        while (-1 < sr.Peek()) {
            try 
                string name = sr.ReadLine();
                string email = sr.ReadLine();
                var lvi = new ListViewItem(name.Substring(name.IndexOf(":") + 1));
                lvi.SubItems.Add(email.Substring(email.IndexOf(":") + 1));

                    // instead of adding this item to the list
                    // --> no more this:: listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
                    // just "accumulate" it 

                accumulator.Add(lvi);
                countit++;
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
        }

        // no need to manually close the reader
        // sr.Close();
        // the using clause will close it for you
        numberofforums = countit;
    }

    return accumulator.ToArray();
}
```

Okay.. So we've created an array of `ListViewItem`.
"So what?" you might think.

Well, for each and every `Add` invocation on your ListView, the ListView will try to react graphically (even if the GUI thread is occupied it will still try). What this reaction is is not for this answer to be concerned. What you must understand is that instead of `Add` you could call `AddRange` which takes a primitive array of `ListViewItem` as its parameter. That will cause just one graphical reaction for all the set of `ListViewItem` instances which means it will speed up your app a lot.

### So here's ingredient number 2

Make another method which calls `LoadItems` and then calls `AddRange` on the `ListView`:

```
public void SomeOtherPlace() {
    string filePath = @"....";
    ListViewItem[] items = LoadItems(filePath);
    this.listView1.Items.AddRange( items );
}
```

This will have already given your app the extra speed you were looking for, but even if the next step will not make your app *elegant*, it will surely help.

### And ingredient number 3 :: Asynchrony

It would be grand if your UI didn't freeze while the `LoadItems` method was being called.

This "non freezing" ability can be achieved in many ways, but the most modern and coolest way is to use `Task<T>` and the `async` and `await` operators introduced in .NET 4.5 and C# 5.0.

If you don't have a clue about what these things are then, just enjoy the first two ingredients but don't hesitate to learn about the entities I've mentioned.

Basically what you need to do is:

- make sure you can't possibly call `SomeOtherPlace()` twice, since what we're about to do is to make this a possibility. So if you have a button's event handler, for instance, which is calling `SomeOtherPlace` then we should disable that button and reenable it once we're done
- we will make the `SomeOtherPlace()` method be an `async` method, which allows it to `await` tasks
- we will run the `LoadItems` code on a separate thread all nicely wrapped in a `Task<ListViewItem[]>` and `await` it on the GUI thread

Let's go. The first change is this:

```
public void SomeOtherPlace() {
```

becomes

```
public async void SomeOtherPlace() {
```

Secondly, we disable the button I talked about:

```
public async void SomeOtherPlace() {
    this.button1.Enabled = false;

    ...

    this.button1.Enabled = true;
}
```

Third, we turn this line:

```
    ListViewItem[] items = LoadItems(filePath);
```

into this:

```
    ListViewItem[] items = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => LoadItems(filePath));
```

Now your method should look something like this:

```
public async void SomeOtherPlace() {
    string filePath = @"....";
    ListViewItem[] items = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => LoadItems(filePath));
    this.listView1.Items.AddRange( items );
}
```

Hope I didn't forget anything.
Good luck and don't settle for not understanding how things work under the hood!

Answer (score 0):

Use listView1.Items.AddRange instead of adding one ListViewItem at a time. This should improve your load time.